# How to delete registry key by using RegistryKey object as handle

Tags: c#, winapi, registry, registrykey

I have a function (credit to [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface)) that opens a registry symlink and returns a `RegistryKey` **handle**:

```
public static RegistryKey OpenSubKeySymLink(this RegistryKey key, string name, RegistryRights rights = RegistryRights.ReadKey, RegistryView view = 0)
{
    var error = RegOpenKeyExW(key.Handle, name, REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, ((int)rights) | ((int)view), out var subKey);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        subKey.Dispose();
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
    return RegistryKey.FromHandle(subKey);  // RegistryKey will dispose subKey
}
```

I want to delete this registry symlink by using the return handle of the key.
The functions that allows me to delete Registry keys require to provide the name of the key as a string, but in my case this is a symlink, it is not enough.
I have the `RegistryKey` handle as object and I want to delete it.

I tried to delete it like that but it doesn't accept it:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegDeleteKeyEx", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int RegDeleteKeyEx(
    UIntPtr hKey,
    string lpSubKey,
    uint samDesired, // see Notes below
    uint Reserved);
    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegistryKey key;
    key = OpenSubKeySymLink(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ABC", RegistryRights.ReadKey, 0);
    RegDeleteKeyEx(key, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ABC", 0x100, 0);   // don't know how to delete the RegistryKey handle
}
```

When I type `key.` I see that it as functions for deletion but it again asks for the key path as a string.

Comment: declare hkey as SafeRegistryHandle instead of UIntPtr and pass key.Handle

Comment: you need use `ZwDeleteKey`

Comment: Second parameter should be just `"ABC"`, so `key` needs to refer to its direct parent (and I'd advise you to use a `RegistrySafeHandle` for that. What happens if you open the parent key using the normal `RegistryKey` functions and delete the subkey using `regKey.DeleteSubKey("ABC")`?

Comment: @Charlieface - nothing good happens. this api simply not design for delete exactly hKey. only ZwDeleteKey work here

Comment: @RbMm Firstly, `Zw` is for kernel-mode. For user-mode you would need `NtDeleteKey`. Second, I was saying to delete by accessing the parent first and calling `DeleteSubKey`, which is how you are supposed to do it. It works perfectly fine for normal subkeys, I was asking if it worked with sym-links. Do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @Charlieface - firstly - no any difference in user mode between Zw and Nt api. this is alias and point to the same function. but `ZwDeleteKey` is declared in *wdm.h* when Nt version not declared. *I was asking if it worked with sym-links. Do you know it doesn't work?* - this api not have flag to say - open child as self or if it link - open link target. so it can delete link target instead link key itself. win32 api at all bad design compare ntapi. many functionality is lost. we already have key handle. not need open another key. but no such api in win32 set

Comment: Two more functions to investigate: [`RegDeleteTreeW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdeletetreew) and [`SHDeleteKeyW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shdeletekeyw)

Comment: For DeleteTree MSDN says subkeys and values but does not specify what happens to the handle key. SH registry functions are wrapper functions.

Comment: @SimonMourier and @Charlieface thanks, it accepted it but it didn't delete it eventually. I used both your advises to use `SafeRegistryHandle` and changed the second parameter to `"ABC"` and the key wasn't delete.

Comment: `DllImport("Ntdll.dll")` must be and `SetLastError = false`. CharSet - not play role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undocumented but calling `RegDeleteKey(hKey, @"")` (advapi32) will delete a key by handle (works all the way back to Win95/NT4).

I don't know what the behavior on symlinks is. It most likely deletes the link (if you specifically opened the symlink) and not the target but you just have to check to be sure.

If you don't want to rely on undocumented behavior you have to call [`ZwDeleteKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwdeletekey) (ntdll) as suggested by RbMm.

Comment: Interesting, the function is documented to *not* accept `NULL` but it says nothing about an empty string (which isn't a valid key name anyway)

Comment: @Andres thanks, it maybe work with regular key but not with symbolic registry key. Because my question is only about deleting the handle I would need to accept it but I want to try first to use the `ZwDeleteKey`. I am checking how to pinvoke it and I will update.

Comment: @Simon Mourier showed me how to import `ZwDeleteKey` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649357/how-to-import-zwdeletekey-in-c-external-component-has-thrown-an-exception. Thanks Simon.

Comment: no, RegDeleteKeyW(hKey, L"") not work here, because it anyway do relative open internal and without `OBJ_OPENLINK` flag. so `RegDeleteKeyW(hKey, L"")` delete (or try delete) target of link, instead link itself