# How to import ZwDeleteKey in C#: "External component has thrown an exception"

Tags: c#, winapi, registry, registrykey

I am trying to use [`ZwDeleteKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwdeletekey) to delete a registry symbolic link.
I imported it like that:

```
[DllImport("NtosKrnl.exe", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "ZwDeleteKey", SetLastError = true)]  
private static extern int ZwDeleteKey(SafeRegistryHandle hKey);
```

But after I call it, I receive an exception:

> "External component has thrown an exception"

My full code:

```
[DllImport("NtosKrnl.exe", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "ZwDeleteKey", SetLastError = true)]  
private static extern int ZwDeleteKey(SafeRegistryHandle hKey);  

public static RegistryKey OpenSubKeySymLink(this RegistryKey key, string name, RegistryRights rights = RegistryRights.ReadKey, RegistryView view = 0)
{
    var error = RegOpenKeyExW(key.Handle, name, REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, ((int)rights) | ((int)view), out var subKey);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        subKey.Dispose();
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
    return RegistryKey.FromHandle(subKey);
}  


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegistryKey key;
    key = OpenSubKeySymLink(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ABC", RegistryRights.ReadKey, 0);
    ZwDeleteKey(key.Handle);
}
```

Comment: Use "ntdll.dll" or just "ntdll" not "ntoskrnl.exe" (and you can remove Charset, EntryPoint and SetLastError attributes they're useless and/or wrong here)

Comment: thanks, it works. Please write it as an answer and I will accept it. Just a note, it doesn't delete the symlink but this is a different problem now that I need to solve.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwdeletekey) has the following note: *"If the call to this function occurs in user mode, you should use the name `NtDeleteKey` instead of `ZwDeleteKey`."*

Comment: Side point: you need to dispose your `key` with a `using` block, if you looked at my original code in your previous questions you will see how it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation for [ZwDeleteKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwdeletekey) does mention "NtosKrnl.exe" being the "DLL", but this is wrong, the import definition should be like this instead (plus there's no string involved, the entry point is not ambiguous and the function doesn't set last error):

```
[DllImport("ntdll")]
private static extern int ZwDeleteKey(SafeRegistryHandle hKey);
```